# Nodejs http request with got and proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

I'm trying to send an http request using **got** with proxy but when querying an ip service it doesn't return the proxy ip, how can I check that it's actually working and the request is being tunneled by the proxy?

This is the full code:

```
var got = require('got');
var hpagent = require('hpagent');
var ProxyLists = require('proxy-lists');

async function test(){
let proxiesArray = [];
ProxyLists.getProxies({
    countries: ['us', 'ca']
})
.on('data', function(proxies) {
    proxiesArray = proxiesArray.concat(proxies.filter(p=>p.protocols.includes("https")));
})
.on('error', function(error) {})
.once('end', function() {
    console.log('end!');
});

while(proxiesArray.length == 0) await utils.delay(1);

let ip = proxiesArray[0].ipAddress;
let port = proxiesArray[0].port;
console.log(ip + ":" + port);

let res = got('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', {
    agent: {
        https: new hpagent.HttpProxyAgent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            proxy: `https://${ip}:${port}`
        })
    }
}).then((body) => {
    console.log(body)
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('Error with proxy ' + proxy)
});
}
```